# UIPresentationController present navigation controller view

Tags: ios, uipresentationcontroller

On iOS 14, when presenting a modal navigation controller, non full screen, with UIPresentationController and modalPresentationStyle custom, the navigation bar take account into the safe area top inset (even if prefersStatusBarHidden is true). So, there is a gap equal to the status bar height at the top of the presented view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using the private API method `_viewSafeAreaInsetsFromScene`.

Comment: But using a private API will get you rejected from the App Store, and then where will you be?

Comment: No, not if they are used well! Secretly.